# Unable to like media in instagram from any access token

Tags: instagram, access-token, instagram-api, social-media-like

Since 3 or 4 days ago i'm not able to like any photos from any token, I think they blocked me to like. I still can follow/unfollow users via my application. I also can like photos via instagram iOS app.
This is the error i have:

```
"meta": {
    "error_type":"APINotAllowedError",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message":"you cannot like this media"}
```

Do you know if they will unlock me or it's permanently?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a vendor support question related to a specific account that can only be answered by Instagram support staff who can access that account's information.

Comment: Instagram suggests that we use StackOverflow for questions about API and other stuff. https://instagram.com/developer/support/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram changed the terms for using POST and DELETE requests. You can read more about it here http://developers.instagram.com/post/116410697261/publishing-guidelines-and-signed-requests

If you want to request access to those endpoints you can do it here, if your app is qualified.

[https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/contact/185819881608116#*=*](https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/contact/185819881608116#_=_)

Answer (score 0):

See [API Terms of Use](http://instagram.com/developer/):

```
Do not abuse the API. Too many requests too quickly will get your access turned off
```

Wait for some days and see if they will free you... If you are still having trouble, i would suggest to create a new client and see what happens.